# Create unique filename by adding incremental number

Tags: filenames, increment, autoit

I'm trying to increment file names if a previously numbered one exists.

For example, it should check if "Example.csv" exists. If so, the new file should be called "Example2.csv", then "Example3.csv", "Example4.csv" and so on. Here's my code so far:

```
$fileNum = 2
; The $month variable is defined earler in the script but I'll define another var for this example
$month = "January"
If FileExists("Emissions Log - " & $month & ".csv") Then
    If FileExists("Emissions Log - " & $month & $fileNum & ".csv") Then
        $fileNum += 1
        $file = FileOpen("Emissions Log - " & $month & $fileNum & ".csv", 1)
    Else
        $file = FileOpen("Emissions Log - " & $month & $fileNum & ".csv", 1)
    EndIf
Else
    $file = FileOpen("Emissions Log - " & $month & ".csv", 1)
EndIf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that, you must loop the filenames.

```
$month = "January"

For $i = 0 To 1000 ;max file versions is set to 1000

    If $i = 0 Then
        $num = ''
    Else
        $num = $i
    EndIf

    If Not FileExists("Emissions Log - " & $month & $num & ".csv") then
        $file = FileOpen("Emissions Log - " & $month & $num & ".csv", 1)
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to increment file names if a previously numbered one exists.

[`While`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/While.htm) [`FileExists()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileExists.htm) [`StringReplace()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringReplace.htm). Example:

```
Func _FilenameUnique(Const $sFilenameRequested, Const $sDelimiter = '-', Const $iCountStart = 2)
    Local $iError          = 0, _
          $iCount          = $iCountStart - 1
    Local $sFilenameUnique = $sFilenameRequested

    While FileExists($sFilenameUnique) And Not $iError

        $iCount         += 1
        $sFilenameUnique = StringReplace($sFilenameRequested, '.', $sDelimiter & $iCount & '.', -1)
        $iError          = @error

    WEnd

    Return SetError($iError, $iCount, $sFilenameUnique)
EndFunc
```

`$sFilename = _FilenameUnique('C:\path\file.csv', '')` functions as requested. Include [current time](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm) alternatively:

```
$sFilename = 'C:\path\file_' & @YEAR & @MON & @YDAY & @HOUR & @MIN & @SEC & '.csv'
```