# How to write date and time to a file name?

Tags: file, datetime, autoit

My AutoIt script doesn't work. It should rename files by actual date and time.

```
#include <Date.au3> 
#include <File.au3>
FileMove("C:\file.csv", "C:\file" & _NowDate() & _NowTime() & ".csv")
```

There is no syntax error, but the file isn't renamed. I think Windows rejects symbols like `:` or `/`. How to convert time to this format: `hh-mm-ss_dd-mm-yyyy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can sanitize the output inline

```
#include <Date.au3>
FileMove("file.csv", "file" & stringreplace(_NowTime(5) , ":" , "-") & "_" & 
stringregexpreplace(_NowCalcDate() , "(\d\d\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d)" , "$3-$2-$1") & 
".csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

> "... *how to convert time in this format : hh-mm-ss_dd-mm-yyyy?*"

As per [Documentation - Macro Reference](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/macros.htm) (as there is nothing to convert):

```
Global Const $g_sPathFile = 'C:\file.csv'
Global Const $g_sFormat   = '%s-%s-%s_%s-%s-%s'
Global Const $g_sTime     = StringFormat($g_sFormat, @HOUR, @MIN, @SEC, @MDAY, @MON, @YEAR)
Global Const $g_sNameNew  = StringReplace($g_sPathFile, '.', $g_sTime & '.', -1)

FileMove($g_sPathFile, $g_sNameNew)
```

`yyyymmddhhmmss` -format conforms to string sort (displays chronological order by Windows Explorer).

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46353808/4157124).